# How to change legend labels in scatter matrix

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a scatter matrix that I want to change the labels for. On the right-hand, I want to change the blue color `1` to Say Mystery and the red color `2` to say Science. I also want to change the labels of each graph to label their counterpart [Spicy, Savory, and Sweet]. I tried using dict to relabel but then my charts came out wrong.

[image]

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df,
    dimensions=["Q12_Spicy", "Q12_Sav", "Q12_Sweet", ],color="Q11_Ans"
   )
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column called `Q11_Labels` that maps `1` to `Mystery` and `2` to `Science` from the `Q11_Ans` column, and pass `colors='Q11_Labels'` to the `px.scatter_matrix` function. If you still want the legend to display the original column name, you can pass a dictionary to the labels parameter of the `px.scatter_matrix` function with `labels={"Q11_Labels":"Q11_Ans"}`

Then you can extend this dictionary to include the other column name to display name mappings as well, so that `[Spicy, Savory, Sweet]` are displayed instead of `[Q12_Spicy, Q12_Savory, Q12_Sweet]`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

## recreate random data with the same columns
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), 
    columns=["Q12_Spicy", "Q12_Sav", "Q12_Sweet"]
    )
df["Q11_Ans"] = np.random.randint(1,3,size=100)
df["Q11_Ans"] = df["Q11_Ans"].astype("category")
df = df.sort_values(by="Q11_Ans")

## remap the values of 1 and 2 to their meanings, then pass this as the color
df["Q11_Labels"] = df["Q11_Ans"].map({1: "Mystery", 2: "Science"})

## pass a dictionary to the labels parameter
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df,
    dimensions=["Q12_Spicy", "Q12_Sav", "Q12_Sweet"],color="Q11_Labels",
    labels = {"Q12_Spicy":"Spicy","Q12_Sav":"Savory","Q12_Sweet":"Sweet", "Q11_Labels":"Q11_Ans"}
   )

fig.show()
```

[image]